# jQuery, Ajax get xml data

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

hello i need to get data from xml file,

here is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       var xml;
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "tt.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: xmlParser
            });
        }); 
        function xmlParser(data) {
            xml = data;

            $('#load').fadeOut();

            $(xml).find("column").each(function()
            {

              var $col = $(this); 
              var name = $col.attr("name");
              $("#list").append("<li>"+ $col.text() + "</li>");

            });

        }
    </script>

</head>
<body >

<ul id="list"></ul>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is an example of my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<pma_xml_export version="1.0" xmlns:pma="http://www.phpmyadmin.net/some_doc_url/">
    <!--
    - Structure schemas
-->
<pma:structure_schemas>
    <pma:database name="makes_data" collation="latin1_swedish_ci" charset="latin1">
        <pma:table name="Sept2014">
            CREATE TABLE `Sept2014` (
            `Year` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
            `Make` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
            `Model` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
            `Trim` varchar(73) DEFAULT NULL,
            `Engine Size` varchar(17) DEFAULT NULL,
            `Engine Cylinder` varchar(17) DEFAULT NULL,
            `Engine Compressor Type` varchar(21) DEFAULT NULL,
            `Transmission` varchar(17) DEFAULT NULL
            ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
        </pma:table>
    </pma:database>
</pma:structure_schemas>

    <!--
    - Database: 'makes_data'
-->
<database name="makes_data">
    <!-- Table Sept2014 -->

    <table name="Sept2014">
        <column name="Year">2001</column>
        <column name="Make">Acura</column>
        <column name="Model">RL</column>
        <column name="Trim">3.5 4dr Sedan</column>
        <column name="Engine Size">3.5L</column>
        <column name="Engine Cylinder">6cyl</column>
        <column name="Engine Compressor Type">dd</column>
        <column name="Transmission">AUTOMATIC</column>
    </table>
    <table name="Sept20141">
        <column name="Year">2001</column>
        <column name="Make">bmw</column>
        <column name="Model">RL</column>
        <column name="Trim">3.5 4dr Sedan </column>
        <column name="Engine Size">3.5L</column>
        <column name="Engine Cylinder">6cyl</column>
        <column name="Engine Compressor Type">dd</column>
        <column name="Transmission">AUTOMATIC</column>
    </table>
    <table name="Sept20142">
        <column name="Year">2004</column>
        <column name="Make">Acura</column>
        <column name="Model">RL</column>
        <column name="Trim">3.5 4dr Sedan</column>
        <column name="Engine Size">3.5L</column>
        <column name="Engine Cylinder">6cyl</column>
        <column name="Engine Compressor Type">dd</column>
        <column name="Transmission">AUTOMATIC</column>
    </table>

    <table name="Sept2014">
            <column name="Year">2009</column>
            <column name="Make">Mercedes-Benz</column>
            <column name="Model">E-Class</column>
            <column name="Trim">E550 4MATIC 4dr Sedan AWD</column>
            <column name="Engine Size">5.5L </column>
            <column name="Engine Cylinder">8cyl</column>
            <column name="Engine Compressor Type">dd</column>
            <column name="Transmission">AUTOMATIC</column>
        </table>
        <table name="Sept2014">
            <column name="Year">2005</column>
            <column name="Make">Mercedes-Benz</column>
            <column name="Model">E-Class</column>
            <column name="Trim">E550 4dr Sedan</column>
            <column name="Engine Size">5.5L </column>
            <column name="Engine Cylinder">8cyl</column>
            <column name="Engine Compressor Type">cc</column>
            <column name="Transmission">AUTOMATIC</column>
        </table>
        <table name="Sept2014">
            <column name="Year">2001</column>
            <column name="Make">Mercedes-Benz</column>
            <column name="Model">E-Class</column>
            <column name="Trim">E550 4dr Sedan</column>
            <column name="Engine Size">5.5L </column>
            <column name="Engine Cylinder">8cyl</column>
            <column name="Engine Compressor Type">cc</column>
            <column name="Transmission">AUTOMATIC</column>
        </table>

</database>
</pma_xml_export>
```

it works well, but not like i need to more explain i want to get all column data but separated based on its name attribute category, for example, if i choose the year 2001 i will get data column which name=Make correspond to this year, and when i choose make = Acura i will get model and trim correspond to this make.

example:
year = 2001 =>  make data retreived = { Acura, bmw, Mercedes-Benz}

if i choose make = Acure => Model data retreived = { RL } and Trim data retreived { 3.5 4dr Sedan}

Answer (score 0):

This will filter your objects then put them into an array, however I'm unclear what you want to do with the data after it is retrieved by year:

```
function xmlParser(data) {
    $('#load').fadeOut();

    var property = 2001,
    propertyName = 'year',
    getProperty = 'Make';

    data = $.grep(data, function( obj, index ) {
      return obj[propertyName] == property;
    });

    var collection = [];
    $.each(data, function( index, obj ) {
        collection.push(obj[getProperty]);
    });
    console.log(collection);
}
```

Comment: Please post the that is requested XML-string so I can make a fiddle to adjust the code.